# database node.js to angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I am new to Node.JS and AngularJS and I have made a connection to a database using Node.js (code below)

```
var mysql      = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host     : 'localhost',
    user     : 'root',
    password : '',
    database : 'nodetest'
});

connection.connect();

connection.query('SELECT * from testtable', function(err, rows, fields) {
    if (!err) {
        var test = rows;
        console.log('The solution is: ', test);
        return test;
    } else{
        console.log('Error while performing Query.');
    }
});

connection.end();
```

the database consists of 2 tables (ID and  name) and only has 1 row (1, 'Luuk')

my code gets put through Grunt for compiling.
when I run the script stated above, it give the expected result (`The solution is:  [ RowDataPacket { ID: 1, name: 'Luuk' } ]`)

but when I want to add this to a controller in angularjs, it gives no results

```
app.controller('NameController', function() {
    this.nameList = test;
});
```

how would be fixed?

Comment: Where are you expecting `test` to come from in your controller code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you're confusing concepts.

Angular.js and Node.js are running in a COMPLETELY different environment. Node.js is a server, that is running locally in your machine, which you can access via browser with the url `localhost:3000` for example. But this server can be running on another machine for example, which you would be able to access via IP, something like `123.4.5.678:3000`.

To share data between the `backend` and the `frontend`, you must do this over requests. When you access the localhost via browser, you're doing a request to the server, and the server provide some response, like a HTML page or something like that.

Look this example at the Nodejs Docs

```
http.createServer( function(request, response) {
  response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  response.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(3000);
```

In the response we are returning a plain text. But this can be json, with your search at the database.

And you can do a specific route, like `/getTestTable` which you can call in the Angular, with the `$http` service, and handle this.

I suggest to take a better look at how Node.js works, and Angular.js too.

You would like to take a look too at the Express.js, a framework for Node.

Answer (score 0):

Check the scope of variable test - it is defined inside call back function of connection.query. Try defining variable 'test' globally.